# Replacing \n and empty spaces in reg ex

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, regex

Hi I have a JavaScript json value as

```
{ 's-env': \n   { 'b1:trackingip': \n.  { ........
```

I want to replace all the `\n` and empty spaces 
I am using

```
regex str.replace(/\\/g, "")
```

It is working fine but it only replaces `\` part. `n` is still in there.
Please let me know how to correct the edges replace to remove all `\n` and empty space.

Comment: Try replacing all `\\n` using `str.replace(/\\n/g, "")`. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Also, what is an *empty space*?

Comment: *`\n` and empty spaces* what empty spaces you are talking about except `\n`?

Comment: I am trying to get rid of all the extra characters to get to certain values using json string that was created from xml response. It has to many junk characters and json parsing keeps giving undefined error

Comment: A sample input and expected output is required to decide.

Comment: If you have a "json string that was created from xml response" but "json parsing keeps giving undefined error" (and the "undefined error" is actually a parse error and not something else), then what you need to do is fix the code that creates the JSON string, not try to fix the JSON after the fact. I suspect that your actual problem is in fact elsewhere, but you haven't given us enough information (like, say, what error message you're actually getting) to help solve.

Comment: @Jordan you were right there was parse error too. It was hard to see cause xml is so huge and so many unneeded characters once it was cleaned I saw the parse issue too and fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try matching the the whole phrase '\n' and any empty space like this:

```
str.replace(/(\\n| |\t|\r|\n)/g, '');
```

note that in addition to the string '\n', this also grabs spaces, tabs, carriage returns, and line feeds

the key is using a match expression '()' and providing alternates separated by '|'.

Comment: Why not just `\\n|\s+`? Your replace could unintentionally replace whitespace inside values.

Comment: \s+ would still replace inside values...  honestly i only didn't use it because i couldn't remember if js regex supported it.